# object is an instance of class (java)

Tags: java, object, instance

```
System.out.print("Enter Room Number: ");
int a4 = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
booking[count]= new RoomBooking (a1,a2,a3,a4);
count++;

if (/* if the object is an instance of RoomBooking(subclass) */) {
    for (int y = 0; y < count; y++) {
        if (a4 == (((RoomBooking) booking[y]).getRoomNumber())) {
            System.out.print("Used number, Please Try again");
        }
    }
}
```

---

"if the object is an instance of RoomBooking(subclass)"
How can i write that in java?

Sorry if that doesn't make sense, still learning.

If you need to know what's going on, there are 2 classes. 
Booking (normal Booking) and RoomBooking ( which extends Booking)..
Since we have to create one array which stores a mixture of both, i need to check if the object(a4) is an instance of the RoomBooking so i can compare the numbers.

---

I have tried if ((RoomBooking.class.isInstance(a4))){...}
but it didn't work.

Comment: if (object instanceof RoomBooking)
does object = a4? 

(a4 instanceof RoomBooking)

Comment: This seems kind of like a repost... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014127/

Answer (score 24):

`if (object instanceof RoomBooking) ...`

And an [interesting read](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31)

Answer (score 11):

There is also the `isAssignableFrom`method in `Class`.

```
if(CabinBooking.class.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass())
```

I prefer the method that `@assylias` suggested since it would work even in `object == null` while `isAssignableFrom` would throw an error if the parameter is null. So you must check that the instance is not null.

```
if(object instanceof CabinBooking.class)
```